# Express checkout shipping rates missing

Tags: paypal

Unless I'm missing something there doesn't seem to be a way to calculate shipping based on the customers address using the latest express checkout.

I'm aware that it can be done using the old legacy nvp instant api callback.

Just seems to be slightly ridiculous to not have this if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

It's one of those things to account for. Sales tax is another - also dependent on "where".

You'll get the address *after* a Paypal user "accepts" (aka "approves") your Paypal payment request. You can make adjustments not exceeding 115% of the original total of the payment originally requested.

Usually ok for sales taxes, but depending on your needs, may not work for shipping (e.g. can't do "flat" shipping rates, international shipping or if US, outside of continental US) so may need to account for it in your checkout flow e.g.

- ask user for zip/country (data you can use for "estimate") prior to payment flows
- perhaps restrict and/or make adjustments, if needed (along the 115% limit).

Hth...

Comment: OK thanks for the advise, guess I'll have to use the old legacy systems, as I thought the point of express was to make the user experience simple, if you have to ask for their location prior to them using express it defeats the purpose. There also no guarantee they'll enter the right location and could end up with cheaper shipping than required.

Comment: @dottodot adjustments go both ways - less or more. IINM, the limit is on the "more" (limit of 115%). You can charge (aka "finalize"/"execute" in Paypal terminology) _less_ . Hth.

Comment: The shipping is a flat rate though and there are certain purchases that would be outside the 115% rule.

Comment: @dottodot IMHO, the new flow is much friendlier - no redirects so there's something to it for both user and merchant :) You could do a/b testing and see if it's "worth it" to your bottom line. Best ~

Comment: That's a good point actually using the legacy systems are no where near as user friendly. But that just makes this issue even more frustrating.

Comment: @dottodot Actually, I maybe assuming `REST` is what you're referring to. Mea culpa. See if [this works for you](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/upgrade-integration/)

Comment: That's what I was looking to implement in conjunction with the rest api but at no point during creating a payment are you given the customers address and there are no events on the client side that detect change of address, the only time you get the address is once the payment is executed which is too late.

Comment: @dottodot if you have an existing "legacy" implementation (`NVP`/`Soap`), you can "bolt" the front end/no redirects (not even do any `REST` - everything "else" is still your "legacy" implementation) - sort of "middle ground" if you will

Answer (score 0):

I've made contact with Paypal who have advised they are working on a solution similar to the instant callback api that will work on the latest express UI.